# Unable to change VNC resolution on headless machine

Tags: vnc, manjaro, kde-plasma-5, headless

**The goal:** I want to connect to my headless (no monitors connected) machine using VNC and the GPU for the VNC session should be the real GPU (not a dummy GPU)

**How I tried to set up:**
1.Logged into the remote headless machine using SSH
2.Generated a new xorg.conf file with `sudo nvidia-xconfig -a --allow-empty-initial-configuration`
3.Determined PCI bus identifier of the GPU using `nvidia-xconfig --query-gpu-info`
4.Inserted the busID into xorg.conf under the "Device" section
5.Inserted `Virtual     1920 1080` into the "Display" subsection of the "Screen" section in order to change to the resolution
6.`sudo reboot now`
7.Started the VNC server with `x11vnc -display :0`

**The Problem**
When I connect with VNC, the resolution is very low (probably 640x480), instead of 1920x1080 (specified in the xorg.conf) and I am unable to change that because there are no monitors detected in the Settings.

**My environment**
OS: Manjaro Linux x86_64
DE: KDE Plasma
Kernel: 5.10.7-3-MANJARO
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1080 Ti
Nvidia driver version: 460.32.03

**Windows**
If I fire up Windows on the same machine, the remote desktop connection works perfectly. If Windows is able to do it, Linux should too.

Comment: Not an answer but a little opinion.   What does the GPU matter when doing VNC screen scrapes? (perhaps I need a lesson.. seems not smart to me).. Have you heard of X11 forwarding?  VNC is junk IMHO compared to X11 forwarding which has been built into Linux since the beginning.

Comment: I would like to use GPU in order to be able to run graphic-intensive applications. Windows can do this without any prior configuration. I heard about X forwarding, although never tried, I heard it works much more slowly than VNC.

Comment: The GPU means very little when the screen needs to be copied to a remote machine.  X11 forwarding does the rendering ON the remote machine.  VNC does the rendering on the local machine and copies a bitmap to the remote machine.  The way that the GUI is communicated with and rendered completely differently.  *Slower than VNC* sounds like someone didn't know what they were talking about.  Also.. x11 doesn't try to render EVERYTHING.. just the apps being run remotely (making it more efficient still).  I dont care what you use.. but you should know the facts.